# Print XPS from Google Search without dialog with file name listed in excel file

Tags: vba, xps

I have an Excel file with three column A, B, C; Serial #, File #, Name.

I want to search column A on Google, and print the first page result in XPS format with set directory and File name containing something like this:

"Serial # / File # /   Name"
"1 / 1103 / Mock up Name A. xps"

From various search online, I managed to cut and paste the following code:

```
Const OLECMDID_PRINT = 6
Const OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 1
Const PRINT_WAITFORCOMPLETION = 2

Sub AutoSearch()
 Dim N As Long, i As Long
 N = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
 Dim objIE

 Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

 With ActiveWorkbook
    For i = 2 To N
    objIE.Navigate "http://www.Google.com/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1).Value
    objIE.Visible = 1
    Do While objIE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
        Loop
        objIE.ExecWB OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, 1
 Next i
 End With

End Sub
```

Above code allows me to grab column A name, search in Google, and print in XPS, but I still have no idea how to suppress the printing dialog, or manipulate it to save into the file name format and directory I want.

Being extreme unfamiliar with coding, all the solution for suppressing print dialog that I can find involving with something else other than VBA, but I have no idea how to translate that into vba.

(https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fyuan/2007/02/24/printing-documents-to-microsoft-xps-document-writer-without-user-interaction/)

If you have any solution or better idea, please let me know.

Thank you so much

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to save it in XPS format? also, can you provide a snapshot of your sheet

Comment: [link]{http://s9.postimg.org/627j9ld8f/example1.jpg}

Comment: Hello Zac

Thank you for the reply. It doesn't have to be XPS. As long as, it can save the webpage with the time stamp. The above is the screenshot link for my sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After "some" research and digging around, I found a walk around solution. Since I am not a programmer at all, I came across a freeware called, "http://www.weenysoft.com/free-html-to-pdf-converter.html", which is derived from "http://wkhtmltopdf.org/". For those super coder, the latter approach is better way, since you can tackle the solution more directly and efficiently; however, as for me, I had to stick with the first solution, which cannot give you time stamp on the pdf files it produces.

Thus, I need to use another walk around approach, "File_Name_Stamper.pdf (just google this)", to put the time stamp on my pdf files. To use on multiple files, you just need to use any Macro Recorder.

Again, totally not recommended for any programmers, above approaches are pretty sad, but does the job for the time being.

Cheers.